# Populate dropdown values based on another dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript

I have logic for separation values based on choosen dropdown value. I create logic who works only when there is one filter, when I put all filter I need it gives me emtpy dropdown. I need to make function who give me properly value in grupaProizvoda dropdown when choose some value from vrstaProizvoda. I got values in dropdowns from enums.

I tried this and it works for one filter:

```
onVrstaProizvodaChange(event: Event) {
        this.sifGrupaProizvoda = this.sifGrupaProizvoda.filter(
            (sif) => sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.KREDIT),
        );
}
```

I tried to multiple filter options, but it give me empty grupaProizvoda dropdown for some reason.

```
    onVrstaProizvodaChange(event: Event) {
        this.sifGrupaProizvoda = this.sifGrupaProizvoda.filter(
            (sif) => sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.KREDIT),
        );
        this.sifGrupaProizvoda = this.sifGrupaProizvoda.filter(
            (sif) => sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.AKREDITIV),
        );
        this.sifGrupaProizvoda = this.sifGrupaProizvoda.filter(
            (sif) => sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.GARANCIJA),
        );
        this.sifGrupaProizvoda = this.sifGrupaProizvoda.filter(
            (sif) => sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.KREDITNA_KARTICA),
        );
        this.sifGrupaProizvoda = this.sifGrupaProizvoda.filter(
            (sif) => sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.TEKUCI_RACUN),
        );
        this.sifGrupaProizvoda = this.sifGrupaProizvoda.filter(
            (sif) =>
                sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.TRANSAKCIJSKI_RACUN),
        );
    }
```

I call function in vrstaProizvoda dropdown

```
(change)="onVrstaProizvodaChange($event)"
```

Comment: I highly recommend you to use FormGroup, it will make your life a lot easier with forms and filters

Comment: I think instead of setting `sifGrupaProizvoda ` in every line, you can do one filter and add all these values with OR like this:  sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.KREDIT) || sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.AKREDITIV) etc?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep same data source twice `this.sifGrupaProizvodafilter` and `this.sifGrupaProizvodaRaw` because if you filter data and keep in same source previous data will be lost. Only filtered data will be there.

```
onVrstaProizvodaChange(event: Event) {
    this.sifGrupaProizvodafilter = this.sifGrupaProizvodaRaw.filter(
        (sif) => sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.KREDIT),
    );
    this.sifGrupaProizvodafilter = this.sifGrupaProizvodaRaw.filter(
        (sif) => sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.AKREDITIV),
    );
    this.sifGrupaProizvodafilter = this.sifGrupaProizvodaRaw.filter(
        (sif) => sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.GARANCIJA),
    );
    this.sifGrupaProizvodafilter = this.sifGrupaProizvodaRaw.filter(
        (sif) => sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.KREDITNA_KARTICA),
    );
    this.sifGrupaProizvodafilter = this.sifGrupaProizvodaRaw.filter(
        (sif) => sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.TEKUCI_RACUN),
    );
    this.sifGrupaProizvoda = this.sifGrupaProizvodaRaw.filter(
        (sif) =>
            sif.roditelj === Number(VrstaProizvoda.TRANSAKCIJSKI_RACUN),
    );
}
```